# Bootstrap 4 columns are stacking vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've got a Bootstrap container which has a row composed of two columns.

The column on the right holds an image, and should disappear at screen sizes below medium. At medium screen sizes and above, it should take 7 grid columns. The column on the left should take all 12 columns of the grid at screen sizes below medium, and take 5 columns at other sizes.

Unfortunately, I'm seeing something different-the two columns stack vertically, and the right column does not disappear at smaller screen sizes. What am I doing wrong?

(please disregard the use of "className" instead of "class," this is a React project, that's the React convention.)

```
<div className="container-fluid h-100 w-100">
    <div className="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-around align-items-center h-100">
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around h-100 float-right">
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <h6 className="display-6">Sorry to see you go!</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="backdrop col-md-7 d-none d-md-inline d-lg-inline d-xl-inline d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center h-100" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a side note: You shouldn't need `w-100` with `container-fluid`.

Comment: Thanks, good reminder. Any idea as to how I can fix my layout issue?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap 4? Looks like you need to simplify and remove all the util classes. Why not just use `col-md-5` and `col-md-7`?

Comment: There's no `col-xs` you should use `col` instead. So `col-xs-12` = `col-12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, you are trying to achieve something like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-stretch">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="jumbotron m-0">
                    <h6 class="display-6 m-0">Sorry to see you go!</h6>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="backdrop d-none d-md-flex col-md-7 align-items-center" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);">
                [.backdrop]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Please note, that I've renamed the `className` attributes to the standard `class` in order to have a working example.*

A couple of notes:

- Bootstrap display utility classes are working from the breakpoint and up. For example `.d-md-block` will have its effect in *md*, *lg* and *xl* sizes too. So it's not necessary to write the all.
- I've removed bottom margins from `.jumbotron` and `.display-6` by adding the `.m-0` class in order to allow better vertical alignment.
- `.h-100` classes were removed, as `.align-items-stretch` is stretching the boxes to take up available vertical space.

For sure, the exact implementation depends on a couple of other things as well, but this might make things clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it.